# Button not responding after a few clicks lib-gdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I cant seem to find an answer to this. Why does my start button freeze after a certain amount of clicks(3)? It works for the first 3 clicks and then decides to stop working. I can still see that the screen is responding(the button becomes red when clicked), but the text on it doesn't change. It's like the click listener stopped responding.

```
public class MainMenu implements Screen{

    private Game game;
    private Stage stage;

    private TextButton Start_btn;
    private TextButton LocalWifi_btn;
    private TextButton Internet_btn;

    private TextButton Settings_btn;


    private boolean Start_clicked = false;
    private boolean LocalWifi_clicked = false;
    private boolean Internet_clicked = false;
    private boolean Settings_clicked = false;


    public MainMenu(Game g){
        game = g; //The Wasteland

        stage = new Stage(new ExtendViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),
                Gdx.graphics.getHeight())); //create a new stage with viewport to draw 2d stuff on

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage); //all input set to stage


        Skin skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("gui/uiskin.json"), new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("gui/uiskin.atlas"))); //need this before you can make a gui

        Start_btn = new TextButton("" + Start_clicked, skin);

        Start_btn.setPosition(500, 500);
        Start_btn.setSize(200, 200);
        Start_btn.getLabel().setFontScale(10, 10); //change text size

        Start_btn.addListener(new ClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void touchUp(InputEvent e, float x, float y, int point, int button){
                onStartClicked();
            }
        });
        stage.addActor(Start_btn);

    }

    private void onStartClicked(){

        if(!Start_clicked){
            Start_clicked = true;
            Start_btn.setText("" + Start_clicked);
            Gdx.app.log("Button", "" + Start_clicked);

        }
        else{
            Start_clicked = false;
            Start_btn.setText("" + Start_clicked);
            Gdx.app.log("Button", "" + Start_clicked);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

        //this has to be before anything or else it will be drawn on top of everything else
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1); //set background color
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); //clears the screen

        stage.act(delta); //send ammount of time since last render call, tells it to keep a steady fps

        stage.draw();

    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        // use true here to center the camera
        // that's what you probably want in case of a UI
        stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);


    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?!?!?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't override `touchUp()` without calling `super.touchUp()`, because its messing up the functionality of ClickListener. But that's not what you want to override anyway. You should override `clicked()` so it only triggers if you release the click while still over the button. Or better yet, use a ChangeListener. Buttons already have a ClickListener built in that fires a change event when the button is clicked. Adding another ClickListener is redundant when you can just use a ChangeListener.